# Xceed AvalonDock 2: dock/arrange/split my LayoutDocuments horizontally AND vertically

Tags: avalondock

I have been using AvalonDock 1 for an old project, that needs a refresh/rewrite, so I started looking at AvalonDock 2.

One feature I am missing or not sure how to achive is the ability to freely dock/arrange/split my LayoutDocuments horizontally **AND** vertically. 
My app has no docked parts, just the main area containing documents.

When I start off with several documents tabbed and start to drag one, then I can choose to either split horizontally or vertically.
However, when dragging another document, I can only choose to split the same way as before.

See how the second step has fewer dock/split options below:

[image]

I would like to be able to dynamically dock the window either below the left, the right or both windows.

How can this be achived? It was working with version 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting `AllowMixedOrientation` to `True` in the XAML of your [DockingManager](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DockingManager).

```
<xcad:DockingManager AllowMixedOrientation="True" ...>
</xcad:DockingManager>
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct approach! Thank you very much.